# Mysql errno: 150 Foreign keu constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql

*Error when i try create second table, return error:*

**(errno: 150 Foreign keu constraint is incorrectly formed)**

I´m use dbForgeStudio to execute query´s:

Table 1 - "usuario" first...

```
CREATE TABLE alection.usuario (
  USU_ID BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  USU_NOME TEXT NOT NULL,
  USU_MASP INT(11) NOT NULL,
  USU_SENHA CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  USU_CPF VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  USU_EMAIL TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  USU_REL_NIVEL BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  USU_DATA_CAD TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  USU_CAD_POR INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (USU_ID)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

---

Table 2 - "nivel_acesso" second, my "rule" is:

> if (table2 have child on table1) then (u can´t remove table2 row)

```
CREATE TABLE alection.nivel_acesso (
  NA_ID BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  NA_NIVEL INT(11) NOT NULL,
  NA_DESCRICAO VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (NA_ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_NIVEL_USUARIO FOREIGN KEY (NA_ID)
  REFERENCES usuario(USU_REL_NIVEL) 
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the following line:

```
CONSTRAINT FK_NIVEL_USUARIO FOREIGN KEY (NA_ID)
  REFERENCES usuario(USU_REL_NIVEL)
```

where `usuario(USU_REL_NIVEL)` is neither a `primary key` or nor `unique column`. It is mandatory that the referred column is either `primary key` or  `unique column`.

And also you are referring a `NA_ID`, which is an `AUTO INCREMENT` column that is also illogical.

Comment: Also `NA_ID` is defined as `AUTO INCREMENT` so that is also wrong surely

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sharp eyes :)

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved:**

Only invert FK put:

```
CONSTRAINT FK_NIVEL_USUARIO FOREIGN KEY (NA_ID)
  REFERENCES usuario(USU_REL_NIVEL) 
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

on first Table1 and remove this code from Table2

Thanks Guys

Comment: I have to admit, I dont understand what you are saying here!